# How to create custom Style output in views in Drupal 6 ? besides Grid, Table, HTML list?

Tags: drupal, view, coding-style

I need to alter the output of a view that displays in a in a block in order to apply it to some format of a Jquery UI script so I need the following format for a grouped taxonomy query that I'va configured for some node type..

```
<div id="tab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab1Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab2Title</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab3Title</a></li>
    </ul>

</div>

    <div id="tabs-1">Content2</div>
    <div id="tabs-2">Content2</div>
    <div id="tabs-3">Content3</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a Style Plugin, and expose it to views 2 API.

A complete style plugin is made up of these components:

1. An implementation of [hook_views_api](http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/group__views__hooks.html#gc67ffd4a2f61f9814ee37b541c472c47) so Views will load your include
   files;
2. An implementation of [hook_views_plugins](http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/group__views__hooks.html#g23f6e9972b2ed84fc54b7ff63f44477d) to declare your style
   plugin;
3. An implementation of the [views_plugin_style](http://views2.logrus.com/doc/html/classviews__plugin__style.html) class;
4. A theme preprocess function for your style theme;
5. A theme .tpl.php page.

Here is good reference about extending views 2 with custom modules (from which I taken this component list):
http://groups.drupal.org/node/10129

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own views style-plugin. Look at `views_plugin_style_default.inc` in your views module folder.

Then go to [Style plugins](http://drupal.org/node/193448) and find out more about how to implement a style plugin from your own module.

You basically implement the `hook_views_style_plugins()` and then create your own class that extends `views_plugin_style`.

Best of luck!

Comment: This 'Style Plugins' link is related with Views 1.x, which is obsolete and available only for Drupal 5.x