# Drupal list or table in views global custom text

Tags: drupal, view

I want to display some content through views and to theme accordingly I have used global custom text where I am able to display the things but global custom text is repeating the full content for each row. ie if I want to display rows in a table or list I am not able to do this.

I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888040/how-to-create-custom-style-output-in-views-in-drupal-6-besides-grid-table-ht) which will help me out but it seems too advanced which is not needed in my case.

Is there a easier way implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't you use the Table style (D6/D7: Click on "unformatted" next to "Style" and choose "table")

There are modules, Views Custom Field and Semantic Views that gives some way for you to theme the output without editing tpl.php files.

for a Chuck Norris theming, click on the theme information link in Views UI and choose a proper file name and give that name to a file copied from templates from Views module's folder. Edit it!

Comment: Thanks!! didnt know there is something like style as table :(